# How to skip inserting value to Dynamics in Logic App with condition

Tags: datetime, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I have many date values in CSV which is sent to logic app. In example:

date1;date2;date3;date4;date5;date6;date7
2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30
2011-12-30;;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30;2011-12-30

It is possible that there is empty date in the CSV. I need to insert those dates to Dynamics 365. As I insert those values if I insert the empty date it goes as "", which returns an error: "Cannot convert the literal '' to the expected type 'Edm.DateTimeOffset'.". Same happens if I try to pass null when date2 is empty ("").

Is there way to skip inserting anything with logic app? Or is there some other solution to this?

Comment: how do you read your file in the logic app ? you can just check for null in the logic app and skip it. it is possible

Comment: Its read to json which is then iterated with for each. I can check for null yes but the problem is how to skip it? I could do it with logic app condition block but as there are so many date fields I would need so many branches in the logic app that would be painful.. Ideal would be to have oneliner ie. if(empty(items('For_each')['date2']),null,items('For_each')['date2']). Of course that one does not work as I get same error with null as with "".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you will need to stop sending CRM empty fields.

However, you're transforming the data from the CSV shape to the D356 shape, you need to check the data and not emit the field when the source also does not exist is otherwise invalid.

It seems you're using a Foreach over the input, then creating the D365 message with a Compose Action.  The thing is, the Compose Action doesn't give you much control over the output.

Instead, you should use a Liquid Transform where you can test the input before emitting any field.

[Liquid - Control Flow](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/control-flow/)

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like to do. Question is how to do that? Currently I'm using work around to set datetime.min for D365 and then have workflow in D365, which check date fields and clears them if the value is datetime.min..

Comment: Like I said, where you transform from the CSV shape to the D365 shape, don't emit the empty date fields.  How are you doing that? @Valko

Comment: It's sent to Logic App with http crypted. Decrypt is done with with azure function, which also converts CSV to JSON. (this part not done by me). But if I'm correct even if it would at that point skip putting empty value from JSON it does not help. As when parsing JSON I have schema and then later on I use foreach for body of the JSON. At that point there will be empty anyways if value is not present as I have to insert value if there is one..as it will emit the fields with empty json object. Could try this later today anyways

Comment: @Valko Answer updated with different/better approach.